# Generate SSH ed25519 private key with embedded comment

Tags: python, ssh, cryptography, ssh-keys

So I've been looking at modifying some existing code to make it compatible with Windows as well as Linux/MacOS. There is a generator which currently shells out to `ssh-keygen` via subprocess to produce an SSH private key, and there is also an encoder for a public key which also leverages `ssh-keygen` to extract the comment from the private key and appends it to public key as per the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` convention.

I'd like to change both to use the `crytography` library, but am also open to using something like `pycryptodome`.

The generator and encoder classes are derived from abstract base classes, and since there are obviously other generators and encoders structured this way, I want to avoid modifying the attributes and inputs if possible.

My question is simply:

- Is it possible to construct an SSH private key with a comment (like provided by `ssh-keygen -C <.....>`) via `cryptography.hazmat.primatives` or `pycryptodome`? Or alternatively is there a means to modify the private key constructed via this mechanism to embed the comment without having to shell out to `ssh-keygen`?

i.e.

```
In [77]: from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
    ...: from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ed25519
    ...:
    ...: private_key = ed25519.Ed25519PrivateKey.generate()
    ...: public_key = private_key.public_key()
    ...: private_bytes = private_key.private_bytes(
    ...:     encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    ...:     format=serialization.PrivateFormat.OpenSSH,
    ...:     encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
    ...: )
    ...: public_bytes = public_key.public_bytes(
    ...:     encoding=serialization.Encoding.OpenSSH,
    ...:     format=serialization.PublicFormat.OpenSSH
    ...: )

In [78]: private_bytes
Out[78]: b'-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\nb3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZWQyNTUx\nOQAAACDNXoGj2N3kqzpVkB8swYpri6aO+uat2dpLhlwIoBw4WQAAAIivLJWaryyVmgAAAAtzc2gt\nZWQyNTUxOQAAACDNXoGj2N3kqzpVkB8swYpri6aO+uat2dpLhlwIoBw4WQAAAEAqLwgM46xyVLjk\n/oVJteyl3mxKzZXDiUwlHjZ9OMM4YM1egaPY3eSrOlWQHyzBimuLpo765q3Z2kuGXAigHDhZAAAA\nAAECAwQF\n-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\n'

In [79]: public_bytes
Out[79]: b'ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIM1egaPY3eSrOlWQHyzBimuLpo765q3Z2kuGXAigHDhZ'
```

If I check the contents of the key it's generated without a comment:

```
% ssh-keygen -lf /tmp/id_py_crypto
256 SHA256:jC+9/pxq3fZgeh93c5cFTSZXtrdlcRxQsD46KANsvSY /tmp/id_py_crypto.pub (ED25519)

% ssh-keygen -lf /tmp/id_py_crypto.pub
256 SHA256:jC+9/pxq3fZgeh93c5cFTSZXtrdlcRxQsD46KANsvSY no comment (ED25519)
```